# Using the Scanner class to read a scanner string

Tags: java

I have a problem creating a student class which contains a constructor which takes a Scanner string of a format "Brookes 00918 X12 X14 X16 X21". The conditions should be that there should be a student name and student number and the course codes should start with an "X". I have thrown `IncorrectFormatExceptions` in the case that they are not satisfied. However when I create a test class and enter a string and press enter , for example "abc 123" it doesn't produce an output which is usually the case.

Update: I've changed the code to use a String array tokens however now with the toString() method using "123 abc X12" it gives a Null Pointer Exception. It works when I put "123 abc" in the constructor

Update:Seems to work now forgot to initialize the arrayList

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Student extends UniversityPerson{
    private String studentNumber="";
    private List<String> courses=new ArrayList<String>();
    private String studentName="";

    public int checkNoofletters(char[] chararray){
        int noofletters=0;
        for (char c:chararray){
            if (Character.isLetter(c)){
                noofletters++;
            }
        }
        return noofletters;
    }
    public String courseListinStr(){
        String stringo="";
        for (String c:courses){
            stringo+=c;
            stringo+=" ";
        }
        return stringo;
    }

    public Student(Scanner scanner) throws IncorrectFormatException{
        int studentNumberCount=0;
        int studentNameCount=0;

        Scanner s=scanner;
        String input=s.nextLine();
        String[] tokens=input.split("\\s");

        for (int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
            char[] chars=tokens[i].toCharArray();

            if (checkNoofletters(chars)==chars.length){//if the number of letters is equal to the character length
                if (studentNameCount==1){throw new IncorrectFormatException("Can only have 1 student name");}
                studentNameCount++;
                this.studentName=tokens[i];
                continue;
            }
            if (tokens[i].matches("[0-9]+")){//add to the studentNumbers list
                if (studentNumberCount==1){throw new IncorrectFormatException("Can only have 1 student number");}
                studentNumberCount++;
                this.studentNumber=tokens[i];

                continue;
                }

            if (!tokens[i].startsWith("X")){
                throw new IncorrectFormatException("Course code must start with an 'X'");
            }

            System.out.println(tokens[i]);
            courses.add(tokens[i]);

        } 

        if (studentNumber=="" || studentName==""){
            throw new IncorrectFormatException("Must have 1 student Number and Student Name");
        }

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //return String.format("%s %s", studentName,courseListinStr());
        return String.format("Student: %s %s", studentName,studentNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to do something like this:

```
Scanner s=scanner;
String input = s.nextLine();
String[] tokens=input.split("\\s");
```

Now you can test all your conditions:

```
if (tokens.size() < yourNumber) throw new Exception("add here");
if (tokens[2].charAt(0)!='X') throw new Exception("add here");
```

and so on; it should be rather easy to create your Student Object based on your requirements.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply I decided to use your method of putting the characters in the String array tokens, however now I seem to get a NullPointerException. Is there any suggestion you could give me on where I'm getting the exception?

Comment: It means you are using an object which has the null value. You did not initialize it.

Comment: You could be a little bit more explicit and try and show us where u have this error.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I fixed it, I forgot to initialize the courses arraylist. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your program is full of errors and I'll list some of them after answering why it doesn't print anything: if you dump all threads you'll see that the main thread is stuck at `next()`, which blocks until next token is available, and effectively never leaves the constructor of the first student

```
if (s.hasNextInt()){
  studentNumbers.add(s.nextInt());
  s.next();
  continue;  // <--------- this line
}
```

I think this is not the only error in your program, so maybe you'd better throw the entire parsing away and restart from scratch.

1. You should create exactly **one** Scanner object for each input stream, not one for parsed object
2. You should **not** pass the scanner to the Student constructor
3. You should **not** put any algorithm in a constructor: make a separate object instead

To simplify your program introduce a Parser class

```
public class Parser {
  public Parser(Reader in) {}
  public boolean hasNext() {}
  public Student next() {}
}
```

and inside `next()` make the parser deal with entire lines (`Scanner.hasNextLine` and `Scanner.nextLine()`) instead of individual tokens, otherwise you'll have to define a custom protocol to mean EOR (end of record)

Dealing with lines is easier to think about, program and test. Once you have the full record, you can further tokenize it with a simple `String.split()`, or directly use regular expressions.

Comment: Hi there thanks for the reply, the points you made were helpful the thing is the question specifically asked me to include a constructor that takes a scanner as a parameter. If I was required to do that what would you suggest I do?

Comment: Well you can use the same Parser class and directly take a Scanner instead of a Reader

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go through, your whole code. But, I would suggest you to use `StringTokenizer` or `split` function and store it in temp array. Then, traverse through your temp array and validate the data.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply, I did use the split function and traversed through an array however it seems to get a null pointer exception. Any idea on where I'm getting the exception?

Comment: I forgot to initialize the arrayList to a new List object, that fixed the problem